# Sparql query does not show Label from RDFS

Tags: sparql

I am trying a code with a ttl file from the Learning SPARQL book from DuCharme from page 51+52 on a Sparql query service on a Fuseki Server. The rdf:Label request does not work. Does anybody know why?

This is the ttl file:

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> . 

 <http://www.learningsparql.com/ns/demo#i93234>
         foaf:nick "Dick" ;  
         foaf:givenname "Richard" ; 
         foaf:mbox "richard49@hotmail.com" ;
         foaf:surname "Mutt" ;
         foaf:workplaceHomepage <http://www.philamuseum.org/> ;
         foaf:aimChatID "bridesbachelor" .
```

This is the query, which does not work:

```
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

 SELECT ?propertyLabel ?value 
 WHERE
 {
  ?s ?property ?value . 
  ?property rdfs:label ?propertyLabel . 
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYqi0.png. Just load http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf. P.S. There is the 2nd edition.

Comment: Sorry not to mention it, but i have uploaded both graphs, still it does not work.

Comment: Do i somehow assign a from command, that he knows to get the label from the second rdf file?

Comment: I just put both codes into one file and uploaded it into Fuseki and it works, but why doesnt it work with 2 graphs?

Comment: I would like to understand why i cannot query external graphs like this:     SELECT * From Named <http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf>     Do i always need to download all rdfs if i use ARQ or Fuseki Sparql queries?

Comment: `From Named <http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf>` works (note the added "http://") on the command line but not in Fuseki where FROM NAMED picks graphs from the dataset because that's what most users want.

Comment: Thank you, the problem for me is just that the command line does not work for me because i get JENA_HOME errors, because for whatever reason the JENA_HOME setting does not work.